# Ensuring repository is singleton in android

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, repository, dagger

I have started using dagger for my kotlin android app. I want to ensure that repository would be initialized only once, so I have added @Singleton scope for repository.Is this enough or are there any design benefits to do some additional steps in plain kotlin to make the class is singleton?

```
@Module
abstract class RepositoryModule{

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun provideRepository(someRepo : SomeRepo): Repository
}



@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityBindingModule::class,
    RepositoryModule::class,
])

interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication>


class SomeRepo @Inject constructor (
     service : Service ,
     anotherService : Service 
) : Repository{
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, if you use this `Somerepo` in the same `Component` it will always be the same instance, if you try to provide from another `Component` it will create another instance and is only kept alive for the lifetime of the component.

You can always put a breakpoint and see the instance and compare it.